# Hibernate is adding 2 entries into database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC with Hibernate for the first time and every time I add something to the database using the Repository It enters it twice.
I tried to see if there is some other places that Beans are being created and I couldn't see anything

spring-servlet.xml

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="repositories"/>


<!-- This sets the default home page-->
<view-controller path="/" view-name="/login"/>
<!-- Sets the default path for all the Resources -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property  name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url"
                    value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yossi2"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="yossi" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>models.entities.CardInUse</beans:value>
            <beans:value>models.entities.Cards</beans:value>
            <beans:value>models.entities.Customer</beans:value>
            <beans:value>models.entities.Purchases</beans:value>
            <beans:value>models.entities.Subscription</beans:value>
            <beans:value>models.entities.UserCredentials</beans:value>
            <beans:value>models.entities.Vendor</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="applicationContextProvder" class="com.controllers.ApplicationContextProvider"/>
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/db")
public String dbTester(){
    UserCredentialsRepository userCredentialsRepository = applicationContext.getBean(UserCredentialsRepository.class);
    UserCredentials user = new UserCredentials();
    user.setUsername("yossisilb");
    user.setPassword("hello");
    user.setGroup("admin");
    user.setVendor(null);

    userCredentialsRepository.saveUserCreds(user);
   return "vendorLanding";
}
```

And my Repository:

```
    @Repository
public class UserCredentialsRepository implements repositories.UserCredentialsRepository {

@Autowired
public SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
public void saveUserCreds(UserCredentials creds) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(creds);
}
```

Comment: Are you posting to the controller twice? What does your page look like?

Comment: Ye you are right its being called twice. Why does this happen?

Comment: I removed the context Listener and It only creates the Controller once now, But the method is still being called twice

Comment: Perhaps you have a double post problem? You could run an http debugging proxy like Fiddler or just use the network tab in Chrome developer tools to see if the URL is getting posted to twice.